# Is not mutableStateOf working with arrays to refresh values as well?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using mutableStateOf to refresh values on screen but it not working with arrays though it compiler (Android Studio) excepts arrays version of it.

```
 var stringValues0 = arrayOf("1", "2")
 var oneValue0 = "1"

 @Composable
   fun showThem() { 

      var stringValue by remember {mutableStateOf(stringValues0) }
      var oneValue by remember {mutableStateOf(oneValue0) }


   Column {

          Text(text = oneValue)

          Row {

             for(k in stringValue.indices) {
               
                  Text(text = stringValue[k])
               
              }
          
           }
     }
 }
```

In this code, if oneValue had been changed we can see it on screen. But if stringValues0's one item or whole of it changed it is not shown on screen.

This feels pretty idiotic there must be something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your list as `mutableStateListOf`. In this way you can do any operations like `add()` and `remove()`.

```
    var initialValues = arrayOf("1", "2")
    val stringValue = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>()}

    //Initial setup
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        stringValue.addAll(initialValues)
    }
 
    //To display
    Row {
        for (value in stringValue) {
            Text(text = value)
        }
    }

    //To add an element
    Button(
         onClick = {stringValue.add("5")}
    ) {
       //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worked like this, meh.

You just change oneArrayItem value in showThem when stringValues0 string is adjusted. In my case I change array value with button in showThem.

```
var stringValues0 = arrayOf("1", "2")
var oneValue0 = "1"

@Composable
fun showThem() { 

  var oneArrayItem by remember {mutableStateOf("") }
  var oneValue by remember {mutableStateOf(oneValue0) }


Column {

      Text(text = oneValue)

      Row {

         for(k in stringValue0.indices) {

              oneArrayItem = stringValues0[k]
           
              Text(text = oneArrayItem)
           
          }
      
       }

    //
    //

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify stringValue instead of stringValue0,stringValue is modified by remember to remember its state.
then you can:

```
var stringValues0 = arrayOf("1", "2")
var oneValue0 = "1"

@Composable
fun showThem() {

var stringValue by remember { mutableStateOf(stringValues0) }
var oneValue by remember { mutableStateOf(oneValue0) }

Column {
    Text(text = oneValue)
    Row {
        for (k in stringValue.indices) {
            Text(text = stringValue[k])
        }
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        stringValue[0] = "3"
        stringValue = stringValues0.copyOf()
    }) {

    }
  }

}
```